# Lookup table with compound key

Tags: powershell

I am looking for efficient lookup tables in PowerShell

Naive approach is not efficient for large data

```
$data = `
    @(
        @{
            A = 1;
            B = 2;
            C = 3;
        },
        @{
            A = 4;
            B = 5;
            C = 6;
        },
        @{
            A = 7;
            B = 8;
            C = 9;
        }
    )

# looking for value C base on pair (A, B)

function FindC
{
    param
    (
        [int] $A,
        [int] $B
    )

    $data | `
        Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.A -eq $A) -and ($_.B -eq $B) } | `
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty C
}
```

I think, efficient way would be to use hashtables but it is unclear what to do with compound keys. We cannot use hashtables, PSObject or PSCustomObject because they don't have equality implemented

```
> @{ A = 1; B = 2; } -eq @{ A = 1; B = 2; }
False
> [PSObject] @{ A = 1; B = 2; } -eq [PSObject] @{ A = 1; B = 2; }
False
> [PSCustomObject] @{ A = 1; B = 2; } -eq [PSCustomObject] @{ A = 1; B = 2; }
False
```

I don't want to implement my own data classes for such simple cases. So the only thing I found so far is tuple

```
> [Tuple]::Create(1, 2) -eq [Tuple]::Create(1, 2)
True
```

So we can use tuples

```
$hashtable = @{}
foreach ($entry in $data)
{
    $hashtable[[Tuple]::Create($entry.A, $entry.B)] = $entry.C
}

function FindC
{
    param
    (
        [int] $A,
        [int] $B
    )

    $hashtable[[Tuple]::Create($A, $B)]
}
```

Anyone knows more elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: Tuple should work just fine. If you want to use Hashtable only for any reason then you can implement your own method like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521905/how-to-compare-associative-arrays-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Hashtables then you can override the Equals method and provide your own definition for equality. Check this question on how to do this: [How to overload the PowerShell inbuilt class's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749906/how-to-overload-the-powershell-inbuilt-classs-methods/36750053#36750053)