# How to overload the PowerShell inbuilt class's methods

Tags: powershell, overloading

Can I overload the PowerShell inbuilt class's methods? If yes then how? Any code sample would be great.

Essentially, I am trying to overload the Equals method of a Hashtable Dictionary PowerShell object to do appropriate comparisons.

I know that you can overload a cmdlet or a function in PowerShell and whatever is the latest definition that is taken up. But I am trying to overload not a cmdlet or a function, but trying to overload inbuilt method for existing class. I have already checked this post: [Function overloading in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940722/function-overloading-in-powershell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can overload it from C# code in this manner:

```
$Source = @"
    class MyHashTable : HashTable
    {
        public override Equals(...) { ... }
    }
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

$x = New-Object MyHashTable ...
```